# Counting the number of each character in a file

Tags: java, char, filereader

I'm reading the contents of a text file char by char, then I've sorted them in ascending order and count the number of times each char occurs. When I run the program my numbers are way off, for example there are 7 'A' in the file, but I get 17. I'm thinking this means either something is wrong with my counting, or the way I'm reading the chars. Any ideas on what is wrong?

```
public class CharacterCounts {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        String fileName = args[0];
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName)));
        ArrayList<Character> vals = new ArrayList<Character>();
        ArrayList<Integer> valCounts = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        while(in.read() != -1){
            vals.add((char)in.read());
        }

        Collections.sort(vals);

        //This counts how many times each char occures,
        //resets count to 0 upon finding a new char.
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < vals.size(); i++){
            if(vals.get(i - 1) == vals.get(i)){
                count++;
            } else {
                valCounts.add(count + 1);
                count = 0;
            }
        }

        //Removes duplicates from vals by moving from set then back to ArrayList
        Set<Character> hs = new HashSet<Character>();
        hs.addAll(vals);
        vals.clear();
        vals.addAll(hs);

        //System.out.print(vals.size() + "," + valCounts.size());

        for(int i = 0; i < vals.size(); i++){
            //System.out.println(vals.get(i));
            System.out.printf("'%c' %d\n", vals.get(i), valCounts.get(i));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are boxing the chars anyway, I would suggest simply using a `Map<Character, Integer>` instead. Fast than sort+count, and smaller memory footprint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
if(vals.get(i - 1) == vals.get(i)){
```

Both are completely different references and they are not at all equals. You have to compare their value.

You want

```
if(vals.get(i - 1).equals(vals.get(i))){
```

Comment: Wouldn't auto-boxing convert them to `char` automatically? It seems to be counting matches.

Comment: @4castle Nope. While adding, each time a new Charater object getting inserted.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ my numbers are correct now, so thank you for that. The first char I print is the '\n' character, so it doesn't display in the console. Is there anyway I can force that to display correctly?

Comment: @Raviga Just do "if the character equals '\n', display (whatever instead)"

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overcomplicating your count logic. In addition you call `read()` twice in the loop so you are skipping every other value.

```
int[] counts = new int[256]; // for each byte value
int i;
while ((i = in.read()) != -1) { // Note you should only be calling read once for each value
    counts[i]++;
}


System.out.println(counts['a']);
```

Comment: What code would you use to print out the 3 most common letters?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use regex instead, the code will be more flexible and simple. Have a look at the code below:

```
 ...
 final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
 final StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
 //read content in a string builder
 while(reader.ready()) {
    contents.append(reader.readLine());
 }
 reader.close();

 Map<Character,Integer> report = new TreeMap<>();
 //init a counter    
 int count = 0;
 //Iterate the chars from 'a' to 'z'
 for(char a = 'a';a <'z'; a++ ){
     String c = Character.toString(a);

      //skip not printable char
      if(c.matches("\\W"))
          continue;

      String C = c.toUpperCase();
      //match uppercase and lowercase char
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[" + c + C +"]", Pattern.MULTILINE);
      Matcher m = pattern.matcher(contents.toString());
         while(m.find()){
             count++;
         }

         if(count>0){
             report.put(a, count); 
         }
         //reset the counter
         count=0;

      }

      System.out.println(report);
     ...
```